# insert an anchor tag using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an app (that I didn't write) that generates the following:

```
    <div class="page-header"><h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <a href="item_view.php">
            <img src="icons/item.png"> Purchased Items</a>
        </div>
        <!-- other tags &c. -->
      </div></h1>
    </div>
```

I have access to a javascript hook, and jquery is available, that I can make customizations in. The end result I want is:

```
    <div class="page-header"><h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <a href="order_view.php">
            <img src="icons/order.png"> Order Info</a>
          <a href="item_view.php">
            <img src="icons/item.png"> Purchased Items</a>
        </div>
        <!-- other tags &c. -->
      </div></h1>
    </div>
```

I've tried everything I can think of, with no success.

HOW DO I:
Using jQuery, select the "Purchased Items" anchor, and insert the "Order Info" anchor+image before it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is basically selecting the anchor and prepending it with two new elements:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var template = "<a href='order_view.php'><img src='icons/order.png'> Order Info</a>";
  $("a[href='item_view.php']").prepend(template);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-header">
  <h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <a href="item_view.php">
            <img src="icons/item.png"> Purchased Items</a>
        </div>
        <!-- other tags &c. -->
      </div>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I finally arrived at something similar:

    $j('a[href="item_view.php"]').eq(0).before(template);

Answer (score 0):

I finally arrived at something similar:

```
$j('a[href="item_view.php"]').before(template);
```

I had come close a few times, but too many hours at the keyboard and I had been typing:

```
$j('a [href=="item_view.php"]').before(template);
```

Sometimes close isn't good enough.

Thanks for making me rethink it!